# How do I make my div slider automatic and manually navigable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

http://jsfiddle.net/qga2o2qd/1/
This is the code that enables the slider to slide automatically, but in order to make the manual navigation possible, I commented it out.

```
setInterval(function()
{
    if(x==divs.length-1)
    {
        $("#div4,#div3,#div2").animate({right:"0%"},1000);
        x=0;
        return;
    } 
var width=divs[x].width();
divs[x].animate({right:"100%"},"slow");
x+=1;

},3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Already Done The Automation. You Should Just Call One Of Right or Left Functions In The Interval: I've Updated Your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Svvift/qga2o2qd/2/)

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $("#right").click();

},3000);
```

Comment: You Can Use Left Sliding Too. This Is Just A Call To That Function In The Interval.